# Navigation Subform not displaying

Tags: ms-access

I have been searching for days and I can't quite figure this out. All of a sudden the second form on my navigation form no longer displays. This second form is to add new clients and it contains a subform of it's own to enter the clients insurance information. The data entry and allow additions properties on both are set to yes. The visibility is also set to yes on both. Any ideas as to what happened and/or how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I'm still not sure what happened but I performed a compact & repair again (it was like the 10th time) and all of a sudden it was back working again.